# Bootstrap 4 dropdown is not working in a project generated with create-react-app

Tags: jquery, reactjs, bootstrap-4, dropdown

My project uses `create-react-app` and I'm trying to implement a drop-down. To implement Bootstrap, I've copied the source code of the CSS file and pasted in an SCSS file. I then generated the CSS using `node-sass-chokidar` and imported the Bootstrap theme in `App.scss` file, and `App.js` at the root project imports the `App.css`, because importing the SCSS won't work:

**App.scss**:

```
@import "./styles/bootstrap.scss";
@import ...
@import ...
```

**App.js**:

```
import ...
import ...
import "App.css";
...
```

It works like this like a charm, but I'm having problems with the drop-down. I believe it's due to jQuery. I tried adding the module to the project and using `import "jquery";` and `import $ from "jquery";` within the component that makes use of the drop-down classes, as well as importing the jQuery CDN in `index.html`. Both cases did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need more than the Bootstrap CSS and jQuery.
You need the Bootstrap JavaScript loaded too.
See the [getting started](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/) docs.
The Bootstrap JavaScript should be loaded after jQuery. By the way, you can use the "slim" version if jQuery.